# Separate worksheets into separate files

Tags: excel, vba

This creates the same file but I was trying to split multiple worksheets into individual files.

```vb
Sub Split_Sheet_into_ExcelFiles()
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheet.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath & "\" & Sheet.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Only thing that I see is that you are using `ActiveWorkbook` to read the path while you loop over the sheets of `ThisWorkbook`. If `ThisWorkbook` is not the Active Workbook at the start of the routine, you might get an unexpected path.

Comment: Explicitly declare your workbooks.  Create 2 variables for the ActiveWorkbook and the new Workbook (I use curWkbk and newWkbk). Assign the ActiveWorkbook to curWkbk and when you create the new workbook assign it to newWkbk when you call Sheet.Copy (newWkbk = Sheet.Copy).

Answer (score 0):

### Export Each Sheet to an Individual File

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportSheets()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Export Sheets"
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = swb.Path
    
    If Len(dFilePath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path cannot be determined." & vbLf & "Please save the " _
            & "workbook before using this procedure.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook, ssh As Object, sshCount As Long
    
    For Each ssh In swb.Sheets
        If ssh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then ' sheet is visible
            ssh.Copy
            Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
                dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath & "\" & ssh.Name
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            sshCount = sshCount + 1
        'Else ' sheet is not visible; do nothing!?
        End If
    Next ssh

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox sshCount & " sheet" & IIf(sshCount = 1, "", "s") _
        & " exported.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```